# Minimize Boilerplate

Tags: c#, boilerplate

I need to implement some classes that inherit from the interface below. Many of the implementations differ only in the value returned by `P`. How can I minimize the number of lines of code?

```
public class A // I cannot change it
{
    public A(string _) { }
    //...
}

public interface I // I cannot change it
{
    A P { get; }
    void f();
    //...
}

public class B : I // many similar classes: they differ by signature, only
{
    public static A StaticP => new A("signature");

    public A P => StaticP;

    public void f()
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for a [codereview.se]

Comment: You can move f(), etc into an abstract base class

Comment: @user700390 I'm not allowed to change `I`.

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm not sure that asking for a solution is equivalent to _code review_.

Comment: You don't have to change `I` - just implement `I` in a base class that `B` and the rest of the classes inherit.

Comment: how about making the derived class generic

Comment: @pm100 Is it possible to pass the signature as a template parameter? I'm using c# version 7.x.

Comment: you can have the signature as an argument of the constructor

Comment: @pm100 The signature is static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the code from f(), etc. into an abstract base class.  Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseI : I
{
    public abstract A P { get; }

    public void f()
    {
        //...
    }

    //...
}

public class B : BaseI
{
    public static A StaticP => new A("signature");

    public override A P => StaticP;
}
```